# Could you use levitate on the dirt or ground?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock

Specifically, if a thing was visibly charging me from outside combat could you levitate 500lbs of dirt further ahead of it, but in spell range, making a hole for it to fall into. Then simply allow the 500lbs of dirt to gently float back onto its head?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No

Levitate affects “**One** creature or object of your choice”.

500lb of dirt is several hundred thousand objects.

It’s also only about 5 cubic feet so over a 5x5 foot square it would lift about 2.5 inches.

Comment: Dale M, is there guidance regarding what constitutes "an object?" For example, I think a shield is described as an object, although it is made out of several pieces attached to one another... much like a clump of dirt.

Comment: A clump of dirt that's already stuck together would probably be valid. An 500-pound area of dirt would not, on its own, be a valid target unless it was somehow actually stuck together already.

Comment: @Lexible more than happy to - ask a question about it